# Passing external shell script variable via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

When I stumble across an evil web site that I want blocked from corporate access, I edit my named.conf file on my bind server and then update my proxy server blacklist file. I'd like to automate this somewhat with a bash script. Say my script is called "evil-site-block.sh" and contains the following:

```
ssh root@192.168.0.1 'echo "#date added $(date +%m/%d/%Y)" >> /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf; echo "zone \"$1\" { type master; file \"/etc/zone/dummy-block\"; };" >> /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf'
```

It is then run as

```
$ evil-site-block.sh google.com
```

When I look at the contents of named.conf on the remote machine I see:

```
#date added 09/16/2014
zone "" { type master; file "/etc/zone/dummy-block"; };
```

What I can't figure out is how to pass "google.com" as $1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem: Your entire command is put into single quotes – obviously so that bash expressions are expanded on the server and not locally.

But this also applies to your `$1`.

Simple solution: “Interupt” the quotation by wrapping your local variable into single quotes.

```
ssh root@192.168.0.1 'echo "#date added $(date +%m/%d/%Y)" >> /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf; echo "zone \"'$1'\" { type master; file \"/etc/zone/dummy-block\"; };" >> /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf'
```

NB: `\"$1\"` → `\"'$1'\"`.

NOTE: This solution is a simple fix for the one-liner as posted in the question above. If there's the slightest chance that this script is executed by other people, or it could process external output of any kind, please have a look at [Charles Duffy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877636/3908235).

Comment: This isn't safe against intentionally malicious arguments. Given as this is code being invoked in response to security incidents and running as root, such safety is probably a legitimate concern.

Comment: I agree, but we're talking about some hack-ish helper script. A proper solution for blacklist management would look different, anyway. ;)

Comment: For a more explicit example: Consider the case where `$1` is `'"$(rm -rf /)"'` (where those outer quotes are literal text rather than syntax). I'd rather allow an attacker to put garbage in named.conf than allow them to run arbitrary commands on my name server.

Comment: I think lxg's answer is what I need. I escaped that puppy *almost* every way I could except... I'm not concerned about named.conf being edited by another process, and this is a quick method to block access to sites being referenced in spam emails, etc. Thnaks!

Comment: @mrodmac, if you're extracting text from spam emails (by definition, malicious content) and feeding that text into a script which will, for some values of that text, **execute arbitrary commands as root**, I'd argue that you really could use some additional paranoia around how you treat security. :)

Comment: ...which is to say: The advice here has shell injection vulnerabilities. If you've heard folks rant about "bobby tables" issues in insecure database code, this is the shell equivalent.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy, I appreciate your concern (truly) but I don't really see how updating named.conf this way vs. actually logging into the server and editing it there is much different. root only has ssh access from my box and requires a password. The command is not arbitrary and the data inserted is specific. What am I missing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm fully aware of the fact that this is not a universal solution, but the context of this question is IMHO a simple shell one-liner which needed to be fixed. However, I'll add a note to the answer that the solution should not be applied in proper scripts.

Comment: @mrodmac, if you were only ever going to use this script with site names that you looked at personally and were certain weren't malicious (that is to say, formed in such a way as to exercise bugs in the script), this would be fine. If you told this script to block a site with a name chosen to trigger a bug, however, that name could embed a command which would then be invoked on your server.

Comment: ...so, part of the reason I object to this answer is that the question is posed in a very generic way: It asks how to pass variables across ssh process boundaries. You ask a generic question, and some of the people who have the same question are going to have that question in contexts where security is important and human review of data used as arguments isn't happening. StackOverflow exists to create a reusable knowledge base, after all; letting that knowledge base be full of pitfalls reduces its utility.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, this will only be run manually after sites are verified. This may not be the forum, but can you point me to an example of what you mean by "block a site with a name chosen to trigger a bug"? Thanks!

Comment: @mrodmac, there's an example of such a malicious name in the current rev of my answer (`'$(rm -rf /)'.spammer.com`). Mind you, those quotes are intended to be literal -- so if you were typing this at a shell prompt, it might look more like `$'\'$(rm -rf /)\'.spammer.com'`, or `"'"'$(rm -rf /)'"'".spammer.com"`.

Comment: @mrodmac, ...of course, there are lots of ways someone could make that name look more harmless -- like spelling it out in hexadecimal with escapes rather than ASCII, f'rinstance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, OK, got it, no that ain't gonna happen. And again, I do appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you **don't** want this to be two separately redirected `echo` statements -- doing that is both inefficient and means that the lines could end up not next to each other if something else is appending at the same time.

Second, and much more importantly, you don't want the remote command that's run to be something that could escape its quotes and run arbitrary commands on your server (think of if `$1` is `'$(rm -rf /)'.spammer.com`).

Instead, consider:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^ above is mandatory, since we use features not found in #!/bin/sh

printf -v new_contents \
  '# date added %s\nzone "%s" { type master; file "/etc/zone/dummy-block"; };\n' \
  "$(date +%m/%d/%Y)" \
  "$1"
printf -v remote_command \
  'echo %q >>/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf' \
  "$new_contents"
ssh root@192.168.0.1 bash <<<"$remote_command"
```

`printf %q` escapes data such that an evaluation pass in another bash shell will evaluate that content back to itself. Thus, the remote shell will be guaranteed (so long as it's bash) to interpret the content correctly, *even if the content attempts to escape its surrounding quotes*.