# Can't parse a string with brace expansion operations into a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sh

have some problem with shell script.

In our office we set up only few commands, that available for devs when they are trying ssh to server. It is configured with help of .ssh/authorized_keys file and available command for user there is bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh


if [[ $1 == "--help" ]]; then
        cat <<"EOF"


        This script has the purpose to let people remote execute certain commands without logging into the system.
        For this they NEED to have a homedir on this system and uploaded their RSA public key to .ssh/authorized_keys (via ssh-copy-id)
        Then you can alter that file and add some commands in front of their key eg :

        command="/usr/bin/dev.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty

        The user will do the following : ssh testuser@server tail testserver.example.com/2017/01/01/user.log

EOF

exit 0;
fi

# set global variable
set $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

# set the syslog path where the files can be found
PATH="/opt/syslog/logs"


# strip ; or any other unwanted signs out of the command, this prevents them from breaking out of the setup command
if [[ $1 != "" ]]; then
        COMMAND=$1
        COMMAND=${COMMAND//[;\`]/}
fi
if [[ $2 != "" ]]; then
        ARGU1=$2
        ARGU1=${ARGU1//[;\`]/}

fi
if [[ $3 != "" ]]; then
        ARGU2=$3
        ARGU2=${ARGU2//[;\`]/}
fi

if [[ $4 != "" ]]; then
        ARGU3=$4
        ARGU3=${ARGU3//[;\`]/}
fi

# checking for the commands
case "$COMMAND" in
   less)
        ARGU2=${ARGU1//\.\./}
        FILE=$PATH/$ARGU1
        if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
                echo "File doesn't exist"
                exit 1;
        fi
        #echo " --------------------------------- LESS $FILE"
        /usr/bin/less $FILE
        ;;
   grep)
        if [[ $ARGU2 == "" ]]; then
                echo "Pls give a filename"
                exit 1
        fi
        if [[ $ARGU1 == "" ]]; then
                echo "Pls give a string to search for"
                exit 1
        fi
        ARGU2=${ARGU2//\.\./}
        FILE=$PATH/$ARGU2
        /usr/bin/logger -t restricted-command -- "------- $USER Executing grep $ARGU1 \"$ARGU2\" $FILE"
        if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
                echo "File doesn't exist"
                /usr/bin/logger -t restricted-command -- "$USER Executing $@"
                exit 1;
        fi
        /bin/grep $ARGU1 $FILE

        ;;
   tail)
        if [[ $ARGU1 == "" ]]; then
                echo "Pls give a filename"
                exit 1
        fi
        ARGU1=${ARGU1//\.\./}
        FILE=$PATH/$ARGU1
        if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
                echo "File doesn't exist"
                /usr/bin/logger -t restricted-command -- "$USER Executing $@ ($FILE)"
                exit 1;
        fi
        /usr/bin/tail -f $FILE
        ;;
   cat)
        ARGU2=${ARGU1//\.\./}
        FILE=$PATH/$ARGU1
        if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
                echo "File doesn't exist"
                exit 1;
        fi
        /bin/cat $FILE
        ;;
   help)
        /bin/cat <<"EOF"

        # less LOGNAME (eg less testserver.example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/logfile.log)

        # grep [ARGUMENT] LOGNAME 

        # tail LOGNAME (eg tail testserver.example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/logfile.log)

        # cat LOGNAME (eg cat testserver.example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/logfile.log)

        In total the command looks like this : ssh user@testserver.example.com COMMAND [ARGUMENT] LOGFILE

EOF
        /usr/bin/logger -t restricted-command -- "$USER HELP requested $@"
        exit 1
        ;;
   *)
     /usr/bin/logger -s -t restricted-command -- "$USER Invalid command $@"
     exit 1
     ;;
esac

/usr/bin/logger -t restricted-command -- "$USER Executing $@"
```

The problem is next:
when i try to exec some command, it takes only first argument, if i do recursion in files by using {n,n1,n2} - it doesn't work:

```
[testuser@local ~]$ ssh testuser@syslog.server  less srv1838.example.com/2017/02/10/local1.log |grep 'srv2010' | wc -l
0
[testuser@local ~]$ ssh testuser@syslog.server  less srv2010.example.com/2017/02/10/local1.log |grep 'srv2010' | wc -l
11591
[testuser@local ~]$ ssh testuser@syslog.server  less srv{1838,2010}.example.com/2017/02/10/local1.log |grep 'srv2010' | wc -l
0
[testuser@local ~]$ ssh testuser@syslog.server  less srv{2010,1838}.example.com/2017/02/21/local1.log |grep 'srv2010' | wc -l
11591
```

Could someone help me, how can i parse\count command arguments to make it work?
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Can you narrow down the question to only the part that is not working? And how would you like it to be fixed?

Comment: any command doesn't work with {} appropriately

Comment: What you're doing now, though, is just *wrong*, in a lot of ways that go far beyond your question. `set $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`, for example, doesn't do what you want it to do -- if SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND contains `hello "cruel world"`, then you'll get **three** arguments, the first containing `hello`, the second containing `"cruel`, and the third containing `world"`.

Comment: Similarly, there are much better ways to escape a command for remote execution (though *parsing* a command into arguments with shell-equivalent behavior is trickier, we *do* have questions and answers already on the site that go into it).

Comment: Anyhow, `{n,n1,n2}` is split out into multiple arguments at a much earlier phase of parsing than what you get with `set $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` (which only does string-splitting and glob expansion -- also skipping quote removal, hence the bug I mentioned above). You can't go back to that phase without some serious security risks (basically, it's part and parcel with `eval`), so I advise not even trying: If the caller wants to run brace expansion, let *them* do so with their own local shell on the remote end.

Comment: That is to say, if your caller runs `./yourscript less {foo,bar,baz}.txt`, then `foo.txt`, `bar.txt` and `baz.txt` are passed as three separate arguments to your script, and you need to nothing special to handle them. By contrast, if they call `./yourscript less '{foo,bar,baz}.txt'`, they're explicitly telling their shell they *don't* want that behavior, but instead want to read a single file named `{foo,bar,baz}.txt`. Since their remote shell is doing that expansion for you (or not) as appropriate, why are you trying to second-guess?

Comment: (Now, there are a bunch of annoying bugs in ssh's behavior in the multi-argument case, so I actually *do* understand why you'd want to not support it... but the right answer, then, is to *not support it*: Require remote callers to spell out their arguments; if they *must* use brace expansion, let them run `printf -v args_q '%q ' {foo,bar,baz}.txt` -- performing the expansion locally -- and then `./yourscript "less $args_q"`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877636/14122

Comment: BTW, `#!/bin/sh` is the wrong interpreter for this script -- it has a bunch of code that's only valid in ksh derivatives such as bash, so right now it'll break if it's ever run on an OS with a baseline-POSIX `/bin/sh` (such as modern Debian derivatives). Use `#!/bin/bash` instead, unless you're willing to rewrite your code to POSIX-baseline.

Comment: Also, you might try to read and understand [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). It's not *exactly* on-point, but the problems it addresses are based on a very similar set of misconceptions, so getting to a point where you understand the behavior and fixes it describes will be helpful in what you're trying to do here.

Comment: BTW, a **much better** way to pose this question would have been something like "can't parse a string with brace expansion operations into a command" -- you could really express it in just three lines: `SSH_COMMAND='echo {foo,bar,baz}.txt'; set -- $SSH_COMMAND; printf '%s\n' "$@"` -- now, if what you wanted was happening, you'd have each of `echo`, `foo.txt`, `bar.txt` and `baz.txt` on a separate line, whereas what you'd *actually* get was `{foo,bar,baz}.txt` stuck on its own line. That problem is the very essence of what you're asking about here, but is much easier for folks to follow.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more on how code samples in questions should be the **minimal** amount of code needed to reproduce a problem, with unrelated aspects (in this case, ssh) factored out.

Comment: (err, replace `./yourscript` with `ssh yourhost` everywhere I refer to it above, of course).

Comment: To be clear, though: As it is right now, I could break out of this jail without even thinking about it. Oh -- and you also are overwriting `PATH` with the location logs are in. Keep in mind that that variable is also used for lookup of executable locations: This is why the POSIX standard keeps variables with meaning to the system and shell all in all-caps namespace, and reserves lowercase names for application use: So there's a namespace applications can use where they don't need to worry about overwriting system-impacting variables by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less command working now:

```
case "$COMMAND" in
   less)
        if [[ $ARGU1 == "" ]]; then
                echo "Pls give a filename"
                exit 1
        fi
        FILES_LIST=${@:2}
        FILE=(${FILES_LIST//\.\./})
        for v in "${FILE[@]}";do
                v=${v//[;\']/}
                if [ ! -f $v ]; then
                        echo "File doesn't exist"
                fi
                /usr/bin/less $PATH/$v
        done;;
```

tail command works too with 2 and more files, but i can't execute tail -f command on two files unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The number of arguments for a bash script would be `$#`. As a quick example:

```
#!/bin/bash
narg=$#
typeset -i i
i=1

while [ $i -le  $narg ] ; do
    echo " $# $i: $1"
    shift
    i=$i+1
done
```

gives, for `bash tst.sh a b {c,d}`

```
 4 1: a
 3 2: b
 2 3: c
 1 4: d
```

In your script, the command to execute (cat, less, ...) gets explicitly only the second argument to the script. If you want to read all arguments, you should do something like this (note: only a hint, removed all sorts of checks etc..)

```
command="$1"
shift
case $command in
(grep)  pattern="$1"
        shift 
        while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
            grep "$pattern" "$1"
            shift
        done
        ;;
esac
```

note: added some quotes as comment suggested, but, being only a hint, you should carefully look at quoting and your checks in your own script.

Comment: Needs more quotes. `grep "$pattern" "$1"`, at least.